# Unquoting of symbols

Tags: r, dplyr

I was going through the documentation of rename() function in dplyr and found something interesting. They had this concept of unquoting of symbol, but I think I didn't quit grasp the idea from the example.

Unquoting: Like all dplyr verbs, select() supports unquoting of symbols:

```
library(dplyr)

vars <- c(var1 = "cyl", var2 ="am")
select(mtcars, !!vars)
```

And then they had a concept of  `!!!vars`. [tidyverse](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html)

Is it just selecting those two columns and that's it or something special going on. If not, why bother using it?

Comment: This might help [5 min video on tidyeval](https://youtu.be/nERXS3ssntw)

Answer (score 1):

The `select` function supports strings, symbols as input arguments.  When we have more variables, the `!!!` is used

```
select(mtcars, !!!vars)
```

The difference is that here it will also rename the column names to 'var1', 'var2' while in the other case it is stripping off the names