# NSE in tidyverse with select()

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have read a few stackoverflow questions on NSE with dplyr ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656993/how-to-pass-a-named-vector-to-dplyrselect-using-quosures), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46310123/r-dplyr-operate-on-a-column-known-only-by-its-string-name) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471540/unquoting-of-symbols)), but I am still struggling to apply it to my use.

This is my example

This work

```
yo <- tibble(ah = 1:10, meh = 11:20)
yup <- yo %>% select(ABX = meh)
```

But I would like to make this work:

```
i=1
newnames <- c("ABX", "TDX")
yup <- yo %>% select(newnames[i] = meh)
```

A few things, I have tried without success:

```
yup <- yo %>% select_(newnames[i] = "meh")
yup <- yo %>% select(!!rlang::sym(newnames[i]) = meh)
yup <- yo %>% select(as.name(newnames[i]) = meh)
```

Any help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second attempt but with `:=` instead of `=`?

Comment: Thanks @joran, I don't remember ever seen that use of :=  .... and I have use R for a few years now.   Mmmhhh still so much to learn!

Answer (score 2):

```
yup <- yo %>% select(!!newnames[i] := meh)

> yup
# A tibble: 10 x 1
     ABX
   <int>
 1    11
 2    12
 3    13
 4    14
 5    15
 6    16
 7    17
 8    18
 9    19
10    20
```

Not sure if you've read the [programming with dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html), but I've found it very helpful in bettering my understanding of NSE in the tidyverse.

Comment: Oh my ... nope I did not read the vignette.  Homework for the weekend ;-)  I have just skim through it and I have a feeling that a whole new R world is opening to me.